# Why isn't visual map drawn?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm drawing a chart and this part is fine. But the visual map is not shown. What is wrong with the definition of my visual map?

```js
const data = {
  "data": [
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [3, 0],
    [4, 0],
    [5, 0],
    [6, 0],
    [7, 0],
    [8, 0],
    [9, 0],
    [10, 0],
    [11, 0],
    [12, 0],
    [13, 0],
    [14, 0],
    [15, 0],
    [16, 0],
    [17, 0],
    [18, 0],
    [19, 0],
    [20, 0],
    [21, 0],
    [22, 0],
    [23, 0],
    [24, 0],
    [25, 3],
    [26, 1250],
    [27, 1258],
    [28, 1260],
    [29, 1264],
    [30, 1284],
    [31, 1284],
    [32, 1300],
    [33, 1303],
    [34, 1303],
    [35, 1303],
    [36, 1305],
    [37, 1312],
    [38, 1313],
    [39, 1316],
    [40, 1320],
    [41, 1386],
    [42, 8000],
    [43, 8001],
    [44, 8002],
    [45, 8003],
    [46, 8004],
    [47, 8005],
    [48, 8006],
    [49, 8007],
    [50, 8008],
    [51, 8009],
    [52, 8010],
    [53, 8011],
    [54, 8011],
    [55, 8013],
    [56, 8014],
    [57, 8000],
    [58, 8015],
    [59, 8017],
    [60, 8018],
    [61, 8019],
    [62, 8013],
    [63, 8021],
    [64, 8021],
    [65, 8022],
    [66, 8023],
    [67, 8023],
    [68, 8016],
    [69, 8024],
    [70, 8023],
    [71, 8024],
    [72, 8024],
    [73, 8023],
    [74, 8026],
    [75, 8026],
    [76, 8006],
    [77, 8005],
    [78, 7993],
    [79, 7988],
    [80, 8000],
    [81, 8001],
    [82, 7994],
    [83, 8000],
    [84, 8001],
    [85, 8002],
    [86, 8003],
    [87, 8004],
    [88, 8005],
    [89, 8005],
    [90, 8004],
    [91, 8006],
    [92, 8006],
    [93, 8006],
    [94, 8007],
    [95, 8008],
    [96, 8008],
    [97, 8008],
    [98, 8008],
    [99, 8008],
    [100, 8009],
    [101, 8006],
    [102, 8009],
    [103, 8009],
    [104, 8006],
    [105, 8007],
    [106, 8008],
    [107, 8008],
    [108, 8007],
    [109, 8010],
    [110, 8010],
    [111, 7999],
    [112, 8011],
    [113, 8012],
    [114, 8013],
    [115, 8012],
    [116, 8012],
    [117, 8011],
    [118, 8011],
    [119, 8010],
    [120, 8009],
    [121, 8008],
    [122, 8010],
    [123, 8004],
    [124, 8002],
    [125, 8001],
    [126, 8000],
    [127, 7999],
    [128, 7997],
    [129, 7994],
    [130, 7995],
    [131, 7994],
    [132, 7993],
    [133, 7992],
    [134, 7988],
    [135, 7985],
    [136, 7997],
    [137, 7997],
    [138, 7995],
    [139, 7997],
    [140, 7998],
    [141, 7998],
    [142, 7998],
    [143, 7995],
    [144, 7999],
    [145, 7995],
    [146, 7986],
    [147, 7999],
    [148, 8000],
    [149, 8000],
    [150, 7994],
    [151, 7999],
    [152, 7996],
    [153, 7991],
    [154, 7997],
    [155, 7995],
    [156, 7997],
    [157, 7996],
    [158, 7999],
    [159, 7999],
    [160, 7998],
    [161, 7998],
    [162, 8000],
    [163, 8001],
    [164, 8000],
    [165, 7997],
    [166, 7997],
    [167, 7999],
    [168, 7992],
    [169, 8000],
    [170, 8000],
    [171, 8000],
    [172, 8001],
    [173, 8002],
    [174, 8000],
    [175, 7999],
    [176, 8002],
    [177, 8001],
    [178, 8000],
    [179, 7998],
    [180, 7996],
    [181, 7998],
    [182, 7996],
    [183, 7991],
    [184, 7995],
    [185, 7994],
    [186, 7991],
    [187, 7981],
    [188, 7981],
    [189, 7982],
    [190, 7955],
    [191, 7982],
    [192, 7988],
    [193, 7984],
    [194, 7985],
    [195, 7986],
    [196, 7983],
    [197, 7983],
    [198, 7982],
    [199, 7975],
    [200, 7953],
    [201, 7979],
    [202, 7966],
    [203, 7965],
    [204, 7955],
    [205, 7945],
    [206, 7954],
    [207, 7950],
    [208, 7910],
    [209, 7902],
    [210, 7866],
    [211, 7433],
    [212, 7859],
    [213, 7859],
    [214, 7844],
    [215, 7841],
    [216, 7838],
    [217, 7839],
    [218, 7840],
    [219, 7835],
    [220, 7830],
    [221, 7829],
    [222, 7821],
    [223, 7819],
    [224, 7817],
    [225, 7794],
    [226, 7793],
    [227, 7789],
    [228, 7772],
    [229, 7759],
    [230, 7756],
    [231, 1131],
    [232, 1129],
    [233, 1129],
    [234, 1129],
    [235, 1078],
    [236, 1077],
    [237, 1076],
    [238, 1075],
    [239, 1078],
    [240, 1077],
    [241, 1075],
    [242, 1076],
    [243, 1077],
    [244, 1082],
    [245, 1079],
    [246, 1079],
    [247, 1080],
    [248, 1078],
    [249, 1078],
    [250, 1077],
    [251, 1080],
    [252, 4391],
    [253, 4391],
    [254, 4393],
    [255, 4394],
    [256, 4398],
    [257, 4391],
    [258, 4420],
    [259, 4418],
    [260, 4452],
    [261, 4529],
    [262, 4541],
    [263, 4558],
    [264, 4581],
    [265, 4591],
    [266, 4598],
    [267, 4601],
    [268, 4608],
    [269, 4630],
    [270, 4637],
    [271, 4638],
    [272, 4638],
    [273, 4635],
    [274, 4635],
    [275, 4640],
    [276, 4639],
    [277, 4641],
    [278, 4642],
    [279, 4642],
    [280, 4632],
    [281, 4633],
    [282, 4628],
    [283, 4630],
    [284, 4621],
    [285, 4623],
    [286, 4621],
    [287, 4627],
    [288, 4616],
    [289, 4616],
    [290, 3602],
    [291, 3608],
    [292, 3609],
    [293, 3612],
    [294, 3613],
    [295, 3612],
    [296, 3562],
    [297, 3631],
    [298, 3629],
    [299, 3615],
    [300, 3622],
    [301, 3626],
    [302, 3627],
    [303, 3627],
    [304, 3628],
    [305, 3627],
    [306, 3628],
    [307, 3632],
    [308, 3632],
    [309, 3632],
    [310, 3632],
    [311, 3633],
    [312, 3635],
    [313, 8000],
    [314, 8000],
    [315, 8000],
    [316, 7981],
    [317, 8002],
    [318, 7996],
    [319, 7999],
    [320, 7996],
    [321, 8000],
    [322, 8001],
    [323, 8001],
    [324, 7761],
    [325, 8002],
    [326, 8004],
    [327, 7997],
    [328, 7999],
    [329, 7998],
    [330, 7996],
    [331, 7993],
    [332, 7997],
    [333, 7998],
    [334, 7999],
    [335, 7999],
    [336, 8000],
    [337, 8000],
    [338, 8001],
    [339, 8000],
    [340, 8001],
    [341, 8000],
    [342, 8001],
    [343, 8001],
    [344, 8002],
    [345, 8002],
    [346, 8003],
    [347, 8004],
    [348, 8005],
    [349, 8006],
    [350, 8003],
    [351, 7999],
    [352, 7995],
    [353, 7988],
    [354, 7975],
    [355, 7973],
    [356, 7955],
    [357, 7978],
    [358, 7966],
    [359, 7972],
    [360, 7986],
    [361, 7990],
    [362, 7988],
    [363, 7986],
    [364, 7981],
    [365, 7984],
    [366, 7982],
    [367, 7979],
    [368, 7977],
    [369, 7971],
    [370, 7971],
    [371, 7970],
    [372, 7967],
    [373, 7968],
    [374, 7958],
    [375, 7957],
    [376, 7947],
    [377, 7956],
    [378, 7955],
    [379, 7957],
    [380, 7957],
    [381, 7958],
    [382, 7959],
    [383, 7960],
    [384, 7964],
    [385, 7966],
    [386, 7966],
    [387, 7964],
    [388, 7969],
    [389, 7978],
    [390, 7978],
    [391, 7973],
    [392, 7802],
    [393, 7970],
    [394, 7971],
    [395, 7966],
    [396, 7956],
    [397, 7956],
    [398, 7959],
    [399, 7956],
    [400, 7954],
    [401, 7955],
    [402, 7950],
    [403, 7944],
    [404, 7934],
    [405, 7938],
    [406, 7935],
    [407, 7932],
    [408, 7937],
    [409, 7939],
    [410, 7941],
    [411, 7941],
    [412, 7939],
    [413, 7936],
    [414, 7931],
    [415, 7929],
    [416, 7929],
    [417, 7926],
    [418, 7927],
    [419, 7923],
    [420, 7916],
    [421, 7914],
    [422, 7916],
    [423, 7917],
    [424, 7918],
    [425, 7912],
    [426, 7909],
    [427, 7904],
    [428, 7883],
    [429, 7869],
    [430, 7857],
    [431, 7850],
    [432, 7843],
    [433, 7843],
    [434, 7833],
    [435, 7177],
    [436, 7783],
    [437, 7784],
    [438, 7766],
    [439, 7743],
    [440, 7741],
    [441, 7751],
    [442, 7756],
    [443, 7756],
    [444, 7501],
    [445, 7765],
    [446, 7766],
    [447, 7755],
    [448, 7758],
    [449, 7762],
    [450, 7769],
    [451, 7769],
    [452, 7775],
    [453, 7779],
    [454, 7784],
    [455, 7787],
    [456, 7791],
    [457, 7793],
    [458, 7794],
    [459, 7794],
    [460, 7798],
    [461, 7801],
    [462, 7804],
    [463, 7792],
    [464, 7758],
    [465, 7796],
    [466, 7789],
    [467, 7802],
    [468, 7808],
    [469, 7810],
    [470, 7814],
    [471, 7814],
    [472, 7811],
    [473, 7809],
    [474, 7813],
    [475, 7805],
    [476, 7807],
    [477, 7807],
    [478, 7803],
    [479, 7707],
    [480, 7754],
    [481, 7738],
    [482, 7740],
    [483, 7741],
    [484, 7733],
    [485, 7738],
    [486, 7738],
    [487, 7736],
    [488, 7736],
    [489, 4537],
    [490, 4543],
    [491, 4548],
    [492, 4548],
    [493, 4548],
    [494, 4549],
    [495, 4547],
    [496, 4548],
    [497, 4550],
    [498, 4550],
    [499, 4549],
    [500, 4756]
  ],
  "min_val": 0,
  "max_val": 8041
};
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'plot';
div.style.width = '500px';
div.style.height = '200px';
document.body.appendChild(div);
const plot = echarts.init(div);
const option = {
  xAxis: {
    scale: true,
    name: "G",
    nameLocation: "middle",
    nameGap: 30,
    nameTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 16
    },
    splitLine: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    scale: true,
    name: "D",
    nameTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 16
    },
    splitLine: false
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: data.min_val,
    max: data.max_val,
    dimension: 1,
    orient: "vertical",
    right: "10%",
    top: "center",
    itemWidth: "10px",
    itemHeight: "80px",
    text: ["H", "L"],
    calculable: false,
    realtime: false,
    hoverLink: false,
    inRange: {
      color: ["#f2c31a", "#24b7f2"]
    },
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 16
    }
  },
  series: [{
    symbolSize: 1,
    data: data.data,
    type: "line",
    large: true,
    areaStyle: {
      color: {
        type: 'linear',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 1,
        colorStops: [{
            offset: 0,
            color: "#24b7f2"
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: "#f2c31a"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
};
option.series[0].lineStyle = Object.assign({}, option.series[0].areaStyle);
option.series[0].lineStyle.opacity = 0.05;
option.series[0].itemStyle = Object.assign({}, option.series[0].areaStyle);
option.series[0].itemStyle.opacity = 0.05;
plot.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts-en.common.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use common Echarts library without VisualMap component, see [build set](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/master/echarts.common.js) :) Replace in the path `echarts-en.common.js` to `echarts-en.js` and VisualMap will work. For the component you need set `calculable` to `true` if you want to show the handles.

```js
const data = {
  "data": [
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [3, 0],
    [4, 0],
    [5, 0],
    [6, 0],
    [7, 0],
    [8, 0],
    [9, 0],
    [10, 0],
    [11, 0],
    [12, 0],
    [13, 0],
    [14, 0],
    [15, 0],
    [16, 0],
    [17, 0],
    [18, 0],
    [19, 0],
    [20, 0],
    [21, 0],
    [22, 0],
    [23, 0],
    [24, 0],
    [25, 3],
    [26, 1250],
    [27, 1258],
    [28, 1260],
    [29, 1264],
    [30, 1284],
    [31, 1284],
    [32, 1300],
    [33, 1303],
    [34, 1303],
    [35, 1303],
    [36, 1305],
    [37, 1312],
    [38, 1313],
    [39, 1316],
    [40, 1320],
    [41, 1386],
    [42, 8000],
    [43, 8001],
    [44, 8002],
    [45, 8003],
    [46, 8004],
    [47, 8005],
    [48, 8006],
    [49, 8007],
    [50, 8008],
    [51, 8009],
    [52, 8010],
    [53, 8011],
    [54, 8011],
    [55, 8013],
    [56, 8014],
    [57, 8000],
    [58, 8015],
    [59, 8017],
    [60, 8018],
    [61, 8019],
    [62, 8013],
    [63, 8021],
    [64, 8021],
    [65, 8022],
    [66, 8023],
    [67, 8023],
    [68, 8016],
    [69, 8024],
    [70, 8023],
    [71, 8024],
    [72, 8024],
    [73, 8023],
    [74, 8026],
    [75, 8026],
    [76, 8006],
    [77, 8005],
    [78, 7993],
    [79, 7988],
    [80, 8000],
    [81, 8001],
    [82, 7994],
    [83, 8000],
    [84, 8001],
    [85, 8002],
    [86, 8003],
    [87, 8004],
    [88, 8005],
    [89, 8005],
    [90, 8004],
    [91, 8006],
    [92, 8006],
    [93, 8006],
    [94, 8007],
    [95, 8008],
    [96, 8008],
    [97, 8008],
    [98, 8008],
    [99, 8008],
    [100, 8009],
    [101, 8006],
    [102, 8009],
    [103, 8009],
    [104, 8006],
    [105, 8007],
    [106, 8008],
    [107, 8008],
    [108, 8007],
    [109, 8010],
    [110, 8010],
    [111, 7999],
    [112, 8011],
    [113, 8012],
    [114, 8013],
    [115, 8012],
    [116, 8012],
    [117, 8011],
    [118, 8011],
    [119, 8010],
    [120, 8009],
    [121, 8008],
    [122, 8010],
    [123, 8004],
    [124, 8002],
    [125, 8001],
    [126, 8000],
    [127, 7999],
    [128, 7997],
    [129, 7994],
    [130, 7995],
    [131, 7994],
    [132, 7993],
    [133, 7992],
    [134, 7988],
    [135, 7985],
    [136, 7997],
    [137, 7997],
    [138, 7995],
    [139, 7997],
    [140, 7998],
    [141, 7998],
    [142, 7998],
    [143, 7995],
    [144, 7999],
    [145, 7995],
    [146, 7986],
    [147, 7999],
    [148, 8000],
    [149, 8000],
    [150, 7994],
    [151, 7999],
    [152, 7996],
    [153, 7991],
    [154, 7997],
    [155, 7995],
    [156, 7997],
    [157, 7996],
    [158, 7999],
    [159, 7999],
    [160, 7998],
    [161, 7998],
    [162, 8000],
    [163, 8001],
    [164, 8000],
    [165, 7997],
    [166, 7997],
    [167, 7999],
    [168, 7992],
    [169, 8000],
    [170, 8000],
    [171, 8000],
    [172, 8001],
    [173, 8002],
    [174, 8000],
    [175, 7999],
    [176, 8002],
    [177, 8001],
    [178, 8000],
    [179, 7998],
    [180, 7996],
    [181, 7998],
    [182, 7996],
    [183, 7991],
    [184, 7995],
    [185, 7994],
    [186, 7991],
    [187, 7981],
    [188, 7981],
    [189, 7982],
    [190, 7955],
    [191, 7982],
    [192, 7988],
    [193, 7984],
    [194, 7985],
    [195, 7986],
    [196, 7983],
    [197, 7983],
    [198, 7982],
    [199, 7975],
    [200, 7953],
    [201, 7979],
    [202, 7966],
    [203, 7965],
    [204, 7955],
    [205, 7945],
    [206, 7954],
    [207, 7950],
    [208, 7910],
    [209, 7902],
    [210, 7866],
    [211, 7433],
    [212, 7859],
    [213, 7859],
    [214, 7844],
    [215, 7841],
    [216, 7838],
    [217, 7839],
    [218, 7840],
    [219, 7835],
    [220, 7830],
    [221, 7829],
    [222, 7821],
    [223, 7819],
    [224, 7817],
    [225, 7794],
    [226, 7793],
    [227, 7789],
    [228, 7772],
    [229, 7759],
    [230, 7756],
    [231, 1131],
    [232, 1129],
    [233, 1129],
    [234, 1129],
    [235, 1078],
    [236, 1077],
    [237, 1076],
    [238, 1075],
    [239, 1078],
    [240, 1077],
    [241, 1075],
    [242, 1076],
    [243, 1077],
    [244, 1082],
    [245, 1079],
    [246, 1079],
    [247, 1080],
    [248, 1078],
    [249, 1078],
    [250, 1077],
    [251, 1080],
    [252, 4391],
    [253, 4391],
    [254, 4393],
    [255, 4394],
    [256, 4398],
    [257, 4391],
    [258, 4420],
    [259, 4418],
    [260, 4452],
    [261, 4529],
    [262, 4541],
    [263, 4558],
    [264, 4581],
    [265, 4591],
    [266, 4598],
    [267, 4601],
    [268, 4608],
    [269, 4630],
    [270, 4637],
    [271, 4638],
    [272, 4638],
    [273, 4635],
    [274, 4635],
    [275, 4640],
    [276, 4639],
    [277, 4641],
    [278, 4642],
    [279, 4642],
    [280, 4632],
    [281, 4633],
    [282, 4628],
    [283, 4630],
    [284, 4621],
    [285, 4623],
    [286, 4621],
    [287, 4627],
    [288, 4616],
    [289, 4616],
    [290, 3602],
    [291, 3608],
    [292, 3609],
    [293, 3612],
    [294, 3613],
    [295, 3612],
    [296, 3562],
    [297, 3631],
    [298, 3629],
    [299, 3615],
    [300, 3622],
    [301, 3626],
    [302, 3627],
    [303, 3627],
    [304, 3628],
    [305, 3627],
    [306, 3628],
    [307, 3632],
    [308, 3632],
    [309, 3632],
    [310, 3632],
    [311, 3633],
    [312, 3635],
    [313, 8000],
    [314, 8000],
    [315, 8000],
    [316, 7981],
    [317, 8002],
    [318, 7996],
    [319, 7999],
    [320, 7996],
    [321, 8000],
    [322, 8001],
    [323, 8001],
    [324, 7761],
    [325, 8002],
    [326, 8004],
    [327, 7997],
    [328, 7999],
    [329, 7998],
    [330, 7996],
    [331, 7993],
    [332, 7997],
    [333, 7998],
    [334, 7999],
    [335, 7999],
    [336, 8000],
    [337, 8000],
    [338, 8001],
    [339, 8000],
    [340, 8001],
    [341, 8000],
    [342, 8001],
    [343, 8001],
    [344, 8002],
    [345, 8002],
    [346, 8003],
    [347, 8004],
    [348, 8005],
    [349, 8006],
    [350, 8003],
    [351, 7999],
    [352, 7995],
    [353, 7988],
    [354, 7975],
    [355, 7973],
    [356, 7955],
    [357, 7978],
    [358, 7966],
    [359, 7972],
    [360, 7986],
    [361, 7990],
    [362, 7988],
    [363, 7986],
    [364, 7981],
    [365, 7984],
    [366, 7982],
    [367, 7979],
    [368, 7977],
    [369, 7971],
    [370, 7971],
    [371, 7970],
    [372, 7967],
    [373, 7968],
    [374, 7958],
    [375, 7957],
    [376, 7947],
    [377, 7956],
    [378, 7955],
    [379, 7957],
    [380, 7957],
    [381, 7958],
    [382, 7959],
    [383, 7960],
    [384, 7964],
    [385, 7966],
    [386, 7966],
    [387, 7964],
    [388, 7969],
    [389, 7978],
    [390, 7978],
    [391, 7973],
    [392, 7802],
    [393, 7970],
    [394, 7971],
    [395, 7966],
    [396, 7956],
    [397, 7956],
    [398, 7959],
    [399, 7956],
    [400, 7954],
    [401, 7955],
    [402, 7950],
    [403, 7944],
    [404, 7934],
    [405, 7938],
    [406, 7935],
    [407, 7932],
    [408, 7937],
    [409, 7939],
    [410, 7941],
    [411, 7941],
    [412, 7939],
    [413, 7936],
    [414, 7931],
    [415, 7929],
    [416, 7929],
    [417, 7926],
    [418, 7927],
    [419, 7923],
    [420, 7916],
    [421, 7914],
    [422, 7916],
    [423, 7917],
    [424, 7918],
    [425, 7912],
    [426, 7909],
    [427, 7904],
    [428, 7883],
    [429, 7869],
    [430, 7857],
    [431, 7850],
    [432, 7843],
    [433, 7843],
    [434, 7833],
    [435, 7177],
    [436, 7783],
    [437, 7784],
    [438, 7766],
    [439, 7743],
    [440, 7741],
    [441, 7751],
    [442, 7756],
    [443, 7756],
    [444, 7501],
    [445, 7765],
    [446, 7766],
    [447, 7755],
    [448, 7758],
    [449, 7762],
    [450, 7769],
    [451, 7769],
    [452, 7775],
    [453, 7779],
    [454, 7784],
    [455, 7787],
    [456, 7791],
    [457, 7793],
    [458, 7794],
    [459, 7794],
    [460, 7798],
    [461, 7801],
    [462, 7804],
    [463, 7792],
    [464, 7758],
    [465, 7796],
    [466, 7789],
    [467, 7802],
    [468, 7808],
    [469, 7810],
    [470, 7814],
    [471, 7814],
    [472, 7811],
    [473, 7809],
    [474, 7813],
    [475, 7805],
    [476, 7807],
    [477, 7807],
    [478, 7803],
    [479, 7707],
    [480, 7754],
    [481, 7738],
    [482, 7740],
    [483, 7741],
    [484, 7733],
    [485, 7738],
    [486, 7738],
    [487, 7736],
    [488, 7736],
    [489, 4537],
    [490, 4543],
    [491, 4548],
    [492, 4548],
    [493, 4548],
    [494, 4549],
    [495, 4547],
    [496, 4548],
    [497, 4550],
    [498, 4550],
    [499, 4549],
    [500, 4756]
  ],
  "min_val": 0,
  "max_val": 8041
};
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'plot';
div.style.width = '500px';
div.style.height = '200px';
document.body.appendChild(div);
const plot = echarts.init(div);
const option = {
  xAxis: {
    scale: true,
    name: "G",
    nameLocation: "middle",
    nameGap: 30,
    nameTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 16
    },
    splitLine: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    scale: true,
    name: "D",
    nameTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 16
    },
    splitLine: false
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: data.min_val,
    max: data.max_val,
    dimension: 1,
    orient: "vertical",
    right: "10%",
    top: "center",
    itemWidth: "10px",
    itemHeight: "80px",
    text: ["H", "L"],
    calculable: false,
    realtime: false,
    hoverLink: false,
    inRange: {
      color: ["#f2c31a", "#24b7f2"]
    },
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 16
    }
  },
  series: [{
    symbolSize: 1,
    data: data.data,
    type: "line",
    large: true,
    areaStyle: {
      color: {
        type: 'linear',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 1,
        colorStops: [{
            offset: 0,
            color: "#24b7f2"
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: "#f2c31a"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
};
option.series[0].lineStyle = Object.assign({}, option.series[0].areaStyle);
option.series[0].lineStyle.opacity = 0.05;
option.series[0].itemStyle = Object.assign({}, option.series[0].areaStyle);
option.series[0].itemStyle.opacity = 0.05;
plot.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts-en.js"></script>
```